# Tumblr oAuth in .NET or C# get Blog posts

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, tumblr

I'm trying simply to list a secured blog post from tumblr via .NET or C# there is a few non resolved posts and some examples how to post but not get.

Did anyone has some working code for it?

I've tried this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/578418/Integrate-Tumblr-into-Csharp-NET-Website
http://dotnetopenauth.net/

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried contacting Tumblr support to see if it's even possible at this point in time? (There's a lot of things they don't have implemented in the API, yet.)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to get a secured blog post?

The [documentation here](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) is quite straightforward for getting a list of blogs for a certain user and all you need is the ApiKey so you don't need to OAuth at all. It is a GET request like so:

```
api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/posts[/type]?api_key={key}&[optional-params=]
```

You'll need to try this to see if your secured post comes back.

Comment: Yes I know I have this working in jQuery but when your blog has password set you will get nothing. So the only way is to use oAuth